# parse old IIS logs with logstash

Tags: iis, logstash

I have moved to logstash (combined with elastic search and Kibana) from Awsats. However I need to import/parse a few old IIS log files using logstash. The files has been moved to logstash server. However I was not able to find a command to parse the existing log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of links explaining what you'll want to be doing.  Take a look through the rest of the documentation on the official site if you have any more issues.

[10 minute tutorial](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/tutorials/10-minute-walkthrough/).  Part 5 shows what you need to be doing.

[Parsing old logfiles with correct timestamps](https://gist.github.com/jreijn/5098598).  Might be useful as you get into the swing of things.